# How to display contacts with image associated to it in android application?

Tags: android

I am simply displaying the contact list in android application. If there is an image associated with that contact, how can I display the same in application?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: try this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html    or   http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/11/12/contact-image-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to retrieve the image from `Contact`:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
image_uri = cur
      .getString(cur
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
```

To set the image in your activity:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri uri);
```

You can find details in this [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html)